# How to simply delete row in QFormLayout programatically

Tags: qt, layout, pyqt

I have this code:

```
myEdit = QLineEdit()
myQFormLayout.addRow("myLabelText", myEdit)
```

Now I have to remove the row by reference to `myEdit` only:

```
myQformLayout.removeRow(myEdit)
```

But there is no API for that. I can use `.takeAt()`, but how can I get the argument? How do I find the label index, or the index of `myEdit`?

Comment: you should/must use pointers (I assume this is c++ code).

Comment: Try removeWidget(myEdit)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just schedule the widget and its label (if it has one) for deletion, and let the form adjust itself accordingly. The label for the widget can be retrieved using [labelForField](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qformlayout.html#labelForField).

Python Qt code:

```
    label = myQformLayout.labelForField(myEdit)
    if label is not None:
        label.deleteLater()
    myEdit.deleteLater()
```

Comment: ok so should I call layout.update() because it seems to look good only after deleteLater()

Comment: @borovsky. Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. What are you doing before calling `deleteLater()`?

Comment: @borovsky. When a widget is deleted, Qt will recursively delete all of its children as well (this is why it can be a good idea to make sure widgets always have a parent). On the Python side, the garbage-collector will eventually do the cleaning up. However, if you are keeping a reference to an object (e.g. an instance attribute) you may want to explicitly delete it yourself. Once Qt has deleted the C++ part, the Python part becomes unusable, so you will get RuntimeErrors if you attempt to do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

my solution...

in header file:

```
QPointer<QFormLayout> propertiesLayout;
```

in cpp file:

```
// Remove existing info before re-populating.
while ( propertiesLayout->count() != 0) // Check this first as warning issued if no items when calling takeAt(0).
{
    QLayoutItem *forDeletion = propertiesLayout->takeAt(0);
    delete forDeletion->widget();
    delete forDeletion;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually  a very good point... there is no explicit reverse function for `addRow()`.

To remove a row you can do the following:

```
QLineEdit *myEdit;
int row;
ItemRole role;
//find the row
myQFormLayout->getWidgetPosition( myEdit, &row, &role);
//stop if not found  
if(row == -1) return;

ItemRole otheritemrole;
if( role == QFormLayout::FieldRole){
    otheritemrole = QFormLayout::LabelRole;
}
else if( role == QFormLayout::LabelRole){
    otheritemrole = QFormLayout::FieldRole;
}

//get the item corresponding to the widget. this need to be freed
QLayoutItem* editItem = myQFormLayout->itemAt ( int row, role );

QLayoutItem* otherItem = 0;

//get the item corresponding to the other item. this need to be freed too
//only valid if the widget doesn't span the whole row
if( role != QFormLayout::SpanningRole){
    otherItem = myQFormLayout->itemAt( int row, role );
}

//remove the item from the layout
myQFormLayout->removeItem(editItem);
delete editItem;

//eventually remove the other item
if( role != QFormLayout::SpanningRole){
     myQFormLayout->removeItem(otherItem);
     delete otherItem 
}
```

Note that I retrieve all the items before removing them. That's because I don't know if their role will change when an item is removed. This behavior is not specified so I am 
playing safe. In qt designer,  when you remove an item from a form, the other item on 
the row take all the space (which means his role changes...).

Maybe there is a function somewhere and not only I reinvented the wheel but I made a broken one...